# Change the start week on Jquery datepicker ShowWeek

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working on a project utilizing the jQuery datepicker, and am trying to use the showWeek attribute to display the week number next to the calender.

My problem is that I don't want 'week 1' to start on the first of January, but instead on the first of August.

Is there any way I can Implement this?

Thanks

Comment: could you use the calculateWeek and then do the necessary maths to adjust for 1st August?

Comment: Potentially, but I would then need to pass that data back up into the date picker week column - this is the part I can't figure out.

Comment: Have a look at the docs http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-calculateWeek as it might explain what you need to do.

Comment: hey! I checked out the resource  sent me, and after some fiddling figured it out! I have a low rep so i will post the answer in 5 hours or whenever it is

Answer (score 0):

working with the next month not working for prev month so i have disabled prev month.

calender always open with August month if current month less than August than calender start from previous year August.

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dR429/4

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    i = 0;
    month_set = 8;
    var d = new Date();
    week = (Math.ceil(Math.round(((new Date(d.getFullYear() + 1, 1)) - (new Date(d.getFullYear(), 1))) / 86400000) / 7));
    current_year = ((d.getMonth() + 1) >= month_set) ? d.getFullYear() : d.getFullYear() - 1;

    function myWeekCalc() {
        i++;
        return i = (i > week) ? 0 : i;
    }
    $("#d1").datepicker({
        showWeek: true,
        defaultDate: new Date(current_year, month_set-1, 1),
        calculateWeek: myWeekCalc,
        onClose: function () {
            i = 0;
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month) {
            var diff = month - month_set;
            var d = new Date(month + ' 1' + ',' + year);
            if (d.getDay() != '0') {
                i--;
            }
            if (month == month_set) {
                i = 0;
            }
            if (current_year != year && month == month_set) {
                week = (Math.ceil(Math.round(((new Date(year + 1, 1)) - (new Date(year, 1))) / 86400000) / 7));
            }
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-prev").remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery Date Picker **custom Week of Year calculation** and **Moment** library to calculate the week of year based on your locale.

Please refer to this working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/amansour/sez8fLgt/

```js
function myWeekCalc(dt) {
  var dat = moment(dt).locale("en-US");
  return dat.week(); 
  // return dat.isoweek(); // you will have to use firstDay : 1
}

$(function(){

  $("[type='date']").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showWeek: true, 
    firstDay: 0, // 1 being Monday, 0 being Sunday, 6 being Friday
    calculateWeek: myWeekCalc,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    yearRange: "-12:+12"
  });

});
```